# Help identify this electric clothes dryer part from an Asko T701 dryer?

Tags: repair, appliances, dryer

I just replaced the drum rollers on my Asko T701 electric clothes dryer. As I was removing the front frame to access the rollers, this metal part fell out (the Sharpie is just there for scale):

[image: Metal piece]

I don't know what it is. I put the dryer back together and it seems to run fine, but obviously I'd like to figure out what this part is and where to reinstall it. I didn't see exactly where it fell from but it fell into the dryer drum, so I'm figuring it came from the top edge of the front panel (somewhere around this diamond-shaped hole or below it):

[image]

It has no markings or text of any kind on it, and no holes for screws or anything. It doesn't appear in any of the exploded diagrams or parts lists for this dryer that I've been able to find:

http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/Asko-Parts/Dryer-Parts/Model-T701/3365/0151200/P0907020/00005

http://www.greatplainsapplianceparts.com/order/Parts%20Manuals/Asko/ASKO-Dryer/T701%20(TD11A)%20WH%20REV.A.pdf

I also have the service manual for this model and this piece isn't mentioned in the section on removing the front panel (or anywhere else in the manual, as far as I can tell).

Comment: If it works without it, I'd call it a "spare" part.

Comment: You may be right, I've been running the dryer without this part for a month now and it seems to be running fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it does look like a "Guard, Door Switch", part number 8064187.  See item 336 on page 6 of [this](http://www.greatplainsapplianceparts.com/order/Parts%20Manuals/Asko/T700%20Dryer/T712WH%20%28TD25.3%29%20REV.A.pdf).

Unfortunately, that diagram does not show how it is assembled.  It does show that it goes roughly at the top of the opening, just like you suspected.

Comment: Thanks! That at least gives me a better idea of where and in what orientation it was installed.

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered where it goes (I had taken a photo before disassembly).  It sits behind the door switch wires.  It protects the wires from getting caught in the turning drum.  The left side of the plate is aligned with the right side of the plastic body of the door switch.  I can send a photo if that helps.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A photo would be great; if you can't post it, just include the URL and someone will be along to edit it into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This part is called a Door Switch Guard.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence to back up this claim?